# How to set Blender to use identical controls as Unity?

Tags: interface, customization, unity

I am used to Unity's controls and would like to mimic them to Blender to make transitions between the two easier. If you know how, please let me know.

Edit: I apologize, I should have been more specific. Is there a way to import Unity control preferences(key mappings) to Blender? If not, can I remap the basic (by default) left click to rotate view instead of placing crosshairs?

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts, operators behavior or what exactly?

Comment: @Alex, you can change anything that's possible to change with user preferences, but ultimately, these are two different programs and will never be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remap the controls. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, or go to the `Info Header>File>User Preferences`, to open the User Preferences; Then, switch to the edit tab and edit away!

You might also want to take a look at existing presets; However there isn't any for Unity controls...